# Does git rebase ever require a common commit ancestor?

Tags: git, rebase, ancestor

While experimenting with git, I created two branches without a common commit ancestor. Let's call them "master" and "other". The current branch is "master".

As expected, trying to merge "other" via:

```
git merge other
```

produced: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

This is precisely what I expected to happen. Surprisingly to me, running rebase via:

```
git rebase other
```

succeeded.

This was a surprise to me as I assumed that rebase requires a common commit ancestor just like git merge. Does git rebase ever require a common ancestor?

Comment: @matt, thanks! To clarify, if a common ancestor does exist, then I assume rebase will use that in order to cherry-pick only from that point onwards. Correct?

Comment: By default yes (i.e. if you just say `git rebase xxx`), but I never say that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to understand this, as with so much about `rebase`, is to understand two things:

- `rebase` is just `cherry-pick`: it creates new commits based on successive diffs, leaving the old ones in place, and appends them to a target. The difference is merely that, afterwards, cherry picking advances the destination branch name, whereas rebasing transfers the source branch name.
- `git rebase xxx` is a shorthand. The results can therefore be surprising.

The full form of `git rebase` is `git rebase --onto x y z`, which means: "Starting at (but not including) `y`, cherry-pick each successive commit onto `x` until you have cherry-picked `z`."

When you use the shorthand form, `x` is usually the commit that you specify, `z` is the current branch, and `y` is the common ancestor of the two.

But there are circumstances where the shorthand doesn't work that way. In *this* case, there is no common ancestor. So for `y`, Git chooses the "root", i.e. nothingness — just as if you had used the full form with the `--root` option.

---

To illustrate, let us suppose branch `one` consists of commits `a` and then `b`, and branch `two` consists of commits `c` and then `d`:

```
a <-- b (one)

c <-- d (two)
```

Then if you are on `two` and you say `git rebase one`, `one` is `b`, so Git walks backwards from `two` (`d`) to `c` and says to itself: can I cherry-pick the diff "nothingness-to-`c`" onto `b`? If so (because there's no conflict), it does. Then it says: can I cherry-pick the diff "`c`-to-`d`" onto the commit I just created? If so, it does. And that's the end — we've reached the current branch commit — so it stops, and shifts the current branch pointer (`HEAD`) to the last new commit that it created:

```
a <-- b <-- c' <-- d' (two)
      ^
    (one)
```

Note that `c'` and `d'` are copies (ie new commits created by Git). The original `c` and `d` still exist, but no branch name now points at them, and eventually they will be deleted through garbage collection.

Comment: Again, there's a caveat: if you're on branch `b` now, and you run `git rebase --onto x y z`, you will be on branch `z` when it's all done. I think this behavior is evil—you should still be on branch `b` when it's done—and hence I don't recommend the long form, but as long as people are aware of the glitch, it's OK. Just mention the glitch. :-)

Comment: At least (a) it's consistent and (b) you are allowed to rebase a branch you're not on (now)!